# Pin a delegate when using a member-function for a C-Style callback

Tags: c++-cli

When using a member function for a C-Style callback, is it necessary to pin the delegate so that it is not collected or moved by the GC?  I have read several posts on the subject but have not been able to determine if it's necessary or the correct way of implementing.

```
public delegate void FeedCallbackDelegate(int type,void* data,void *param);

public ref class CStyleApiWrapper
{

    public:

    void StartFeed();

    private:

    FeedCallbackDelegate^ managedFeedCallback;
    IntPtr unmanagedFeedCallbackPtr;

    void FeedCallback(int code,int type,void* data,void *param);

};


void CStyleApiWrapper::StartFeed()
{

    managedFeedCallback = gcnew managedFeedCallback(this, &CStyleApiWrapper::FeedCallback);
    unmanagedFeedCallbackPtr = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(managedFeedCallback);

    //Start Feed
    StartFeed((NOTIFY_FUNC)(void*)unmanagedFeedCallbackPtr,0,NULL);

}

void CStyleApiWrapper::FeedCallback(int type,void* data,void *param)
{
    //Process Feed
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calling `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` is not enough to keep the GC from reclaiming your delegate.  You have to `Alloc` a handle with `GCHandle.Alloc` on the delegate.  `Alloc` adds a reference to the delegate, which prevents disposal.  Then you have to `Free` that handle when you are done with it.

Here is a good example page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx.